# My Depth First Search function is receiving the wrong data type even though I'm sending the correct pointer

Tags: c, depth-first-search

My c compiler complains in this code because the "VERTEX* getAdjUnvisitedVertex(VERTEX* first)" function returns an integer instead of a VERTEX pointer.
So when I call the function and try to store it as a "VERTEX*" it crashes. The compiler lets me store it as an integer though.

I only included the two functions that were giving me trouble and my header file. They are all separate files.
I also labeled the line that makes the compiler upset, which is at the end. The actual message that I get from the compiler is: "warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast".

I'm new to c programming and I really don't understand why is sending an integer. Here is my code:

```
//////////My Header File//////////
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]);
typedef struct VERTEX VERTEX;
typedef struct EDGE EDGE;
typedef struct GRAPH GRAPH;


struct VERTEX{
    char c;
    bool isVisited;
    EDGE* p;
};

struct EDGE{
    VERTEX* v;
    EDGE* q;
};

struct GRAPH{
    int numVertices;
    VERTEX** adjLists;
};


VERTEX* makeVertex(char ch);
GRAPH* makeGraph(int length);
void addEdge(GRAPH* graph, char src, char dest);
void displayGraph(GRAPH* graph);
EDGE* makeEdge(VERTEX* vertex);
VERTEX* getAdjUnvisitedVertex(VERTEX* first);
void DFS(GRAPH* graph);
//////////end of my.h/////////////




    ////////getUnvisited function that is supposed to send a vertex////////
    #include "my.h"
    VERTEX* getAdjUnvisitedVertex(VERTEX* first){

    VERTEX* nullVtx = NULL; //This is a null vertex, it is used in case the
                            //function finds the end of the vertex list.

    EDGE* currentE = first->p;//move to next edge that contains next vertex
    if(currentE ==  NULL)//if there is no edge  send an empty vertex pointer
            return nullVtx;
    while((currentE -> v -> isVisited)){ 
            if(currentE -> q == NULL){

                  return nullVtx;
            }
            else
            currentE = currentE -> q;
    }

    return currentE-> v;//This is where it should send a vertex
                        // v is the vertex included in currentE
                        //compiler does not complain here though
    }




//////DFS function that reads an integer instead of vertex pointer////
#include "my.h"

void DFS(GRAPH* graph){
VERTEX* currentV = graph->adjLists[0];
currentV -> isVisited = true;
printf("%c",currentV -> c);

currentV  = getAdjUnvisitedVertex(currentV);//This is where the compiler 
                                 //says that I set a vertex pointer equal to 
                                 // an int
/////warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

}
```

Comment: Show the *actual* error, not your interpretation.

Comment: You can include some details like "expected behavior" and "actual behavior"

Comment: I put a comment at the last line of code and explained what the compiler said.

Comment: also please compile with -Wall and possibly -pedantic flags and post any warnings the compiler complains about before the error. Oh and definition of nullVtx might come handy too

Comment: Oh yeah, nullVtx is just me trying to figure out if the error was coming from the other return statements. So I created a vertex pointer that was empty and sent it through, but didn't work. Originally, those return statements sent out the key word "NULL".  It does not make any difference, it still keeps giving that same error, which is only that one error.

Comment: OK, problem solved I feel stupid now. I forgot to compile my header file..... The whole time I was compiling the c files and forgot that I edited my header file but didn't compiled it.

Comment: If your build system isn't catching header file changes, you really should get this fixed.